# Using function instead alias misunderstands argument in zsh

Tags: docker, zsh

**The problem**

I want to change an already existing alias into a function to specify an argument.

The original code:

```
# support Compose v2 as docker CLI plugin
(( ${+commands[docker-compose]} )) && dccmd='docker-compose' || dccmd='docker compose'
...
alias dcdn="$dccmd down"
...
```

What I want to achieve:

```
# support Compose v2 as docker CLI plugin
(( ${+commands[docker-compose]} )) && dccmd='docker-compose' || dccmd='docker compose'

dcdn() {
    if [ "$1" != "" ]
    then
        '$dccmd -f "$1" down'
    else
        "$dccmd down"
    fi
}
```

**What I expect**

Then when I execute `dcdn` the result expected is `docker-compose down` and if I execute `dcdn docker-compose-dev.yml` it should runs `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down`.

Instead the result I get is '« down» command not found'.

**Things I've tried**

I tried several other ways and nothing work, just givin same error or a strange "permission denied":

```
'$dccmd down'           # $dccmd down not found
"dccmd down"            # $dccmd down not found
"$aliases[dccmd] down"  # «down» not found
"$dccmd" down           # permission denied
'$dccmd' down           # $dccmd not found
$dccmd down             # «down» not found
dccmd down              # «dccmd» not found
```

I even tried a few options with eval with same results.

If I use `docker-compose down` directly it works, but then I'm not using the command stored in dccmd.

NOTE: I saw in other posts that the permission denied could be because dccmd is "" but then why the alias works?

Comment: "Why the alias works?" -- because aliases _are just strings_, so your quoting in defining an alias holds the string together so that it's all a single argument to the `alias` command. A function doesn't need to be (shouldn't be!) specified as a single string, so the quoting that works for an alias is wrong for it; code inside functions gets quoted the same way as regular commands, which is one of the reason functions are better than aliases: you can take what works on a command line, dump it straight into a function, and it still works there.

Comment: btw, `$ddcmd down` failing by trying to run `down` as a command implies that you were testing in a shell where you hadn't previously run `(( ${+commands[docker-compose]} )) && dccmd='docker-compose' || dccmd='docker compose'`

Comment: (As another aside, `a && b || c` **is not the same as** `if a; then b; else c; fi`; treating it as if it's shorthand is a good way to get yourself into trouble; for example, in `a && b || c`, you can have `c` run even if `a` was true, if `b` fails).

Answer (score 2):

Your quoting is incorrect. You don't want the command and all its arguments in a single shell word, which is what quoting the entire command accomplishes.

```
dcdn () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        "$dccmd" -f "$1" down
    else
        "$dccmd" down
    fi
}
```

This *still* won't work, though for a similar reason: if you set `dccmd="docker compose"`, now `"$dccmd"` expands not to two words, a command and its first argument, but to a single word that contains a space, and the string `docker compose` is not the name of a command.

The solution is to define *another* function, not a parameter.

```
if (( ${+commands[docker-compose]} )); then
    dccmd () { docker-compose "$@" }
else
    dccmd () { docker compose "$@" }
fi


dcdn () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        dccmd -f "$1" down
    else
        dccmd down
    fi
}
```

Comment: `"$ddcmd" down` will fail if `ddcmd='docker-compose down'`, so the second branch of your answer is *firmly* the correct one here; it might be worth emphasizing even more strongly that the first code block only solves half the problem.

Comment: If someone wants this as a compact-but-cryptic one-liner: `dcdn(){ ${=commands[docker-compose]:-docker compose} ${=1:+-f $1} down }`.